# How do I initialize vertex locations in a custom JUNG layout?

Tags: java, jung

How do I initialize a new layout with vertex positions known beforehand?

I have created a custom JUNG layout class:

```
public class CustomLayout extends AbstractLayout {

    AbstractLayout subLayout = null;

    final int WIDTH = 500;
    final int HEIGHT = 500;

    public CustomLayout(Graph<Vertex, Edge> graph, Transformer<Vertex, Point2D> init) {
        super(graph, init);

        for (Vertex v : this.getGraph().getVertices()) {
            // Assign each vertex a random initial position.
            setLocation(v, new Point2D.Double(random * WIDTH, random * HEIGHT);
        }

        subLayout = new FRLayout(this.getGraph(), ...?, null);
        // How do I pass each vertices prior positions?

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's what the initializer (`Transformer<V,Point2D>`) is for.  This transformer should return the initial position of any vertex you pass into it.  I see that FRLayout doesn't accept an initializer in its constructor, but looks like you can call `setInitializer()`.

In response to your question, `Transformer` is a generic interface that, when given an input, produces a corresponding output.  The implementation can be whatever you want.  It could serve up a set of statically defined positions, or calculate positions on the fly.  This gives you a lot of flexibility.

You might notice that the interface bears a passing similarity to `Map<K,V>`, and in fact a very simple wrapper implementation could be made as follows:

```
  public class MapTransformer<K,V> implements Transformer<K,V> {

    private final Map<K,V> map;

    public MapTransformer(Map<K,V> map) {
      this.map = map;
    }

    public V transform(K key) {
      return map.get(key);
    }

  }
```

So you could put your positions in a map and then wrap that map in the above `MapTransformer`.

Comment: That makes sense but could you provide a sample that I would pass into the setInitializer() method? Transformer is just an interface and requires some solid implementation.

Comment: JimN's implementation will work just fine.  That said, IIRC there's actually a built-in MapTransformer class in the collections libraries that JUNG uses.