# Jung - Initialize only a single vertex in Transformer

Tags: java, graph, jung

I am working on graph layout using KKLayout. I require only the first vertex to be at the top of the layout and others to be in their default locations.
There is a similar question to this:

[How do I initialize vertex locations in a custom JUNG layout?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12592419/how-do-i-initialize-vertex-locations-in-a-custom-jung-layout)

The transformer in this case applies to all the vertices. How do I apply only to a particular vertex and let the other vertices handled by the KKLayout?

I have tried the option

```
layout.setLocation(firstVertex, 500, 0);
```

and this option does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call Layout.setLocation() followed by Layout.lock(firstVertex, true).